# Remove iOS's iconized footnote back button

Tags: html, ios, css

[image]

I think ever since iOS 8 I've been seeing this icon on my website and several other ones. At first I thought it's how iOS 8 converts all foot notes "back buttons", but then I saw the regular `↩` on many others.

How do I stop iOS from converting `↩` to this ugly icon above in my footnotes?

Comment: I *have* tried `-webkit-appearance: none` for `.footnotes a` — no dice.